# If area under the curve $y=e^x+\cos (x)\ln (x+\sqrt {1+x^2})$ between $x=-a$ to $x=+a $ then what is the possible range of $a$?

Tags: integration

If area under the curve $y=e^x+\cos (x)\ln (x+\sqrt {1+x^2})$ between $x=-a$ to $x=+a $ is less than $3/2$ what is the possible range of $a$?

Comment: Hey you are in Fitjee so you appeared this year for jee or will appear in $2017$

Comment: This year :-)!Will appear for advanced @ArchisWelankar you ?

Comment: Im in 11th all the best !! Hope you clear it!!

Comment: $\cos x\log(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})$ is an odd function. So we need only look at $e^x$ and so the answer is $a\le\ln 2$.

Comment: :) ;) how was mains paper maths was bit lengthy i think

Comment: Ya..I could solve only 20 questions :-P @ArchisWelankar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\ln(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})=\sinh^{-1}x$ which is an odd function. $\cos x$ is an even function, so their product is odd and has zero integral between $x=-a$ and $x=a$. So we need only look at $\int_{-a}^a e^x\ dx$ which is monotonically increasing with $a$. So we find that $a\le\ln 2$.